# Replacing value with ID if matching another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have three columns:

```
      A          B        C
1    TextOne    TextOne    10
2    TextOne    TextTwo    11
3    TextTwo
4    TextTwo
5    TextOne
6    TextTwo
```

Applying the formula below I was expecting the result `10`:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE)),"0",VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE))
```

but I am seeing `NA` and suspect this is connected with the format of the cells.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you're expecting the result "10" then it works (I've just tried it).  What are you getting and what did you expect?

Comment: Yes, I expect this result, but i am return "NA".

Comment: Ah - poss typo in B1 - TextOne or TestOne?  If not, do the vlookup separately and check if its working for you

Comment: I think KAJ has answered your question (I can't see how formula returns NA , though?) but in Excel 2010 why not use IFERROR, that will avoid repeating your VLOOKUP function, i.e. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE),0)`

Comment: I am sorry. I have made a mistake. It is "TextOne". I do the same formula for sample data like this in my post and it is working. Anyway, when I try this with my original data I have problems. I things this is connected with the format of the cells, because when I try to find a value the simple ctrl+f i am warned that there is no such value. That's why I think the VLOOKUP do not find nothings.

Comment: Are the real values numbers? sometimes you get a mismatch between numbers formatted as numbers and numbers formatted as text - does either of these work? `=VLOOKUP(A1+0,$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE)` or `=VLOOKUP(A1&"",$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE)`

Comment: you are doing this formula in an adjacent column and then pasting the result in, correct? Because looking up the value in column A which you are replacing probably will never work. Once the formula is entered the value you are looking up is gone

Comment: @pnuts The issue occurred a year ago. Are you expecting I am holding my excel open or I am remembering what I have try? If you can fix the issue, you are welcome, someone else could meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was initially caused because I was trying to replace the value in cell applying the formula in the same cell.

As @datooo points in his comments:

> Once the formula is entered the value you are looking up is gone

Answer (score 0):

To ‘overwrite’ `TextOne` with `10` the simplest solution may be to filter ColumnA to select `TextOne`, enter `10` and copy down (change filter selection and repeat for `TextTwo` / `11` if required).

For a 'high volume' requirement (lots of replacements) use VLOOKUP (eg as in question) in a separate column and copy that column's results over the top of ColumnA with Paste Special Values.

Comment: in my real situation I am having hundreds of values in for replacement. That's why I am doing this in excel and not in notepad ++